# AnyLogic: How can I made the unit flow into different queues based on queue size

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where there are 2 cash registers and a separate line forms at each register. Customer will join the queue at cash register 1 if the number of customers in that checkout line is less than or equal to the number of customers in the queue for cash register 2. I think I should have the flow chart as below, but I don't know how to set up the condition for the ChooseCheckOut Stage.

[flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WAeX.png)
[ChooseCheckOut Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JaLr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following condition:

```
  queue_Reg1.size() <= queue_Reg2.size()
```